# How to change background color of searched text in listview-cursoradapter while typing in searchview?

Tags: android, listview, text, highlight, android-cursoradapter

I've seen tutorials about highlighting text in `listview` using `Spannable` string but there is none about searching text from database and highlighting in `listview`.

I have a `listview` which gets data from `database/cursor` and shows with the help of `cursoradapter`. I've placed `searchview` in `action bar` to search text from database table.

Now i want that when i type a character or word in searchview, every matched result from `database table` should highlight/change background color of `textview` in `listview`.

I'm confuse about where to perform search operation(in `activity` or `cursoradapter`) and how to display result ?

This code is in activity and i can get result from db with like query.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

    searchText(text + "*");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

    searchText(text + "*");
    return false;
}

private void searchText(String text) {

    if (text != null) {

        localDB.openDB();
        Cursor cursor = localDB.searchDBText(text);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            String message = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(LocalStoreDB.ROW_MESSAGE));

            Log.i("searchText message:", message);
        } else {

            Log.i("searchText message:", "cursor is null");
        }
        cursor.close();
        localDB.closeDB();
    } else {

        Log.i("searchText message:", "input text is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: better post your code you've tried so far, so people can easier to help you

Comment: you can use `filter` list and `SpannableString` for that

Comment: How to use `filter` with this code ? Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologize for answering after a while, but still it would help someone in need.

What i end up doing is pass the text to a method in adapter, then find the text in `bindView()` with `Pattern-Matcher` and highlight the text with `SpannableString`

Following is the code in adapter:

```
public class AdapterSingleChat extends CursorAdapter {

    private static int indexThumb;

    //String to search and highlight
    String textToSearch = null;

    public AdapterSingleChat(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        //caching the column index
        indexThumb = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteStoreDB.ROW_TEXT);
   }

   //ViewHolder()...

   //newView()....

   @Override
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

        //Text from cursor in which search will perform
        String cursorText = cursor.getString(indexText);

        //Spannable string to highlight matching searched words
        SpannableString spannableStringSearch = null;

        if ((textToSearch != null) && (!textToSearch.isEmpty())) {


            spannableStringSearch = new SpannableString(cursorText);

            //compile the pattern of input text
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(textToSearch,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            //giving the compliled pattern to matcher to find matching pattern in cursor text
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cursorText);
            spannableStringSearch.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(
                        Color.TRANSPARENT), 0, spannableStringSearch.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            while (matcher.find()) {

                //highlight all matching words in cursor with white background(since i have a colorfull background image)
                spannableStringSearch.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(
                            Color.WHITE), matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        if(spannableStringSearch != null{

            //if search has performed set spannable string in textview
            holder.tvCursorText.setText(spannableStringSearch);
        }else{

            //else set plain cursor text
            holder.tvCursorText.setText(cursorText);
        }
   }

   //Pass the text from activity(from  SearchManager, EditText or any other input type) here
   private void searchText(String text) {

       this.textToSearch = text;
   }
```

and yes, do not forget to `swapCursor()` or `notifyDataSetChanged()` after inputting words.