# How to change textview background color in listview-cursoradapter when input text matches with cursor string?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement search functionality in listview like text search in browser.

I'm succeeded to search input words in cursor data. But how can i change corresponding word's background color when match is found ?

This is search code in bindview

```
if (searchEnabled) {

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String cursorText = cursor.getString(indexMessage);
        if (s.equals(searchText.toString())) {

            //Change matched word's(textview) background color here
            holder.textMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            Log.i("Cursor Scan:", cursorText);
        }
    }
}
```

After calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it changes color of only last row's textview.

I tried search by getting listview text from `getChildAt()` and partially succeeded, but this view is not consistent and it comes to it's original state on scrolling (since, this listview is inflated from cursor).

I tried following code for searching in listview text:

```
private void updateListView(String textForSearch) {

    LocalStoreDB localDB = new LocalStoreDB(getApplicationContext());
    localMessageDB.openDB();
    Cursor cursorForSearch = localDB.selectMessageDB();
    cursorForSearch.moveToFirst();

    while (cursorForSearch.moveToNext()) {

        int position = cursorForSearch.getPosition();

        View v = listview.getChildAt(position);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

        SpannableString cursorString = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(textForSearch);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(cursorString);
        while (m.find()) {

            cursorString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),
                    m.start(), m.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            Log.i("m.find()", cursorString.toString());
        }
        tv.setText(cursorString);
    }

    localDB.closeDB();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for late answer.

I've answered this question in another thread. Please follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287029/4688535

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color of a textview like this

```
yourTextView.setBackgroundColor("0xff0000ff");
```

I cannot see rest of the code but maybe you have to notify the changes you made after setting color.

Hope it helps

In your case I would try something like this:

```
TextView tv;    
for(int i=0;i<listview.get.getCount();i++){

   tv =(TextView) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
   if(tv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(searchstring)){

       tv.setBackgroundColor("0xff0000ff");
   } 
   else{
       tv.setBackgroundColor("0xffffffff");
   }
}

 listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that, but it changes only last row textview's background color.

Comment: How to notify changes ?

Comment: you can notify like this : yourArrayAdapterForListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); But i guess something else causes problem. How do you fill your listview? Are you using custom data adapter?

Comment: I'm using custom `cursoradapter`. I've tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` and problem with that is, it doesn't scan all rows until there is change in dataset(in this case-cursor).

Comment: Do you have an unique identifier for your listview items, I mean can you identify an item from another without traversing it with a cursor? If so try using this identifier in your while loop  like "if the string you searched equals a list elements text value get the listview item  identifier " and than set the color. I mean not just get the element which your cursor references to.

Comment: check the updates. please tell me if you can help me with this.

Comment: Well, it loses background color on scrolling listview. That's view recycling problem.